# In Python, how do I remove from a list any element containing certain kinds of characters?

Tags: python, regex, list, element

Apologies if this is a simple question, I'm still pretty new to this, but I've spent a while looking for an answer and haven't found anything. I have a list that looks something like this horrifying mess:

```
['Organization name} ', '> (777) 777-7777} ', ' class="lsn-mB6 adr">1 Address, MA 02114 } ', ' class="lsn-serpListRadius lsn-fr">.2 Miles} MORE INFO YOUR LISTING MAP if (typeof(serps) !== \'undefined\') serps.arrArticleIds.push(\'4603114\'); ', 'Other organization} ', '> (555) 555-5555} ', ' class="lsn-mB6 adr">301 Address, MA 02121 } ', ' class="lsn-serpListRadius lsn-fr">.2 Miles} MORE INFO CLAIM YOUR LISTING MAP if (typeof(serps) !== \'undefined\') serps.arrArticleIds.push(\'4715945\'); ', 'Organization} ']
```

And I need to process it so that [HTML.py](http://www.decalage.info/en/python/html) can turn the information in it into a table. For some reason, HTML.py simply can't handle the monster elements (eg. 'class="lsn-serpListRadius lsn-fr">.2 Miles} MORE INFO YOUR LISTING MAP if (typeof(serps) !== \'undefined\') serps.arrArticleIds.push(\'4603114\'); ', etc).  Fortunately for me, I don't actually care about the information in the monster elements and want to get rid of them.

I tried writing a regex that would match all more-than-two-letter all-caps words, to identify the monster elements, and got this:

```
re.compile('[^a-z]*[A-Z][^a-z]*\w{3,}')
```

But I don't know how to apply that to deleting the elements containing matches to that regex from the list. How would I do that/is that the right way to go about it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think your regex is incorrect, to match all entries that contain all-cap words with three or more characters, you should use something like this with `re.search`:

```
regex = re.compile(r'\b[A-Z]{3,}\b')
```

With that you can filter using a list comprehension or the `filter` built-in function:

```
full = ['Organization name} ', '&gt; (777) 777-7777} ', ' class="lsn-mB6 adr"&gt;1 Address, MA 02114 } ', ' class="lsn-serpListRadius lsn-fr"&gt;.2 Miles} MORE INFO YOUR LISTING MAP if (typeof(serps) !== \'undefined\') serps.arrArticleIds.push(\'4603114\'); ', 'Other organization} ', '&gt; (555) 555-5555} ', ' class="lsn-mB6 adr"&gt;301 Address, MA 02121 } ', ' class="lsn-serpListRadius lsn-fr"&gt;.2 Miles} MORE INFO CLAIM YOUR LISTING MAP if (typeof(serps) !== \'undefined\') serps.arrArticleIds.push(\'4715945\'); ', 'Organization} ']
regex = re.compile(r'\b[A-Z]{3,}\b')
# use only one of the following lines, whichever you prefer
filtered = filter(lambda i: not regex.search(i), full)
filtered = [i for i in full if not regex.search(i)]
```

Results in the following list (which I think is what you are looking for:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(filtered)
['Organization name} ',
 '&gt; (777) 777-7777} ',
 ' class="lsn-mB6 adr"&gt;1 Address, MA 02114 } ',
 'Other organization} ',
 '&gt; (555) 555-5555} ',
 ' class="lsn-mB6 adr"&gt;301 Address, MA 02121 } ',
 'Organization} ']
```

Comment: Is there any difference in speed between the two lines?

Answer (score 9):

First, store your regex, then use a list comprehension:

```
regex = re.compile('[^a-z]*[A-Z][^a-z]*\w{3,}')
okay_items = [x for x in all_items if not regex.match(x)]
```

Comment: This seemed like it should work, but for some reason it returns a list without the org names when using my original regex and when using F.J's it just spits out the same list I put in. Not sure why.

Answer (score 3):

Or the very same but without compiling regex:

```
from re import match

ll = ['Organization name} ', '> (777) 777-7777} ', ' class="lsn-mB6 adr">1 Address, MA 02114 } ', ' class="lsn-serpListRadius lsn-fr">.2 Miles} MORE INFO YOUR LISTING MAP if (typeof(serps) !== \'undefined\') serps.arrArticleIds.push(\'4603114\'); ', 'Other organization} ', '> (555) 555-5555} ', ' class="lsn-mB6 adr">301 Address, MA 02121 } ', ' class="lsn-serpListRadius lsn-fr">.2 Miles} MORE INFO CLAIM YOUR LISTING MAP if (typeof(serps) !== \'undefined\') serps.arrArticleIds.push(\'4715945\'); ', 'Organization} ']

filteredData = [x for x in ll if not match(r'[^a-z]*[A-Z][^a-z]*\w{3,}', x)]
```

Edited:

```
from re import compile

rex = compile('[^a-z]*[A-Z][^a-z]*\w{3,}')
filteredData = [x for x in ll if not rex.match(x)]
```

Comment: If you're going to be running the same regex against many items in a list, you *should* compile it. Granted, Python is usually smart enough to compile it for you and cache it, but it's good to be explicit.

Answer (score 1):

without regex

```
def isNotMonster(x):
    return not any((len(word) > 2) and (word == word.upper()) for word in x.split())

okay_items = filter(isNotMonster, all_items)
```

Comment: This returns only the names of the organizations--which actually is also helpful to me right now, so separately thanks, but  it isn't what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
element = 'string_to_search'
for item in y_list_of_items:
    if element in item:
        y_list_of_items.remove(item)
```